# 'TypeError: t.validation is undefined', but it appears to be defined

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a jQuery UI dialog, and I'm trying to validate the input when a button is pressed within the dialog.

However, it's failing when I click the 'Add' button and telling me `TypeError: t.validation is undefined`. As far as I can tell it is defined (in the `init` function).

I suspect I've set it up incorrectly, but I cannot see where for looking. Can someone please tell me how to fix this error?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    optionsDialogFuncs.init();
});

optionsDialogFuncs = {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    init : function(){

        var t = this;   // This object

        $('#add_option').on('click', function(){

            /** Create an object to hold the result of validation checks and the final result */
            t.validtaion = {};
            t.add_option();

        });

    }, // init

    /** Add a single option to the list of predefined options */
    add_option : function(){

        var t = this;   // This object
            tip = $('.validation-tip', '#add-remove-options-form');

        t.validate_add_option();

        /** Check to see if the option was valid */
        if(t.validation.valid !== true){

            /** Output a validation tip to help the user */
            if(t.validation.exists === false){
                tip.text('Please enter an option.');
            } else if(t.validation.exists === false){
                tip.text('This option already exists.');
            } else{
                tip.text('An unknow validation error occured. Please try again.');
            }

        } else{
            // Append input to list of options
            // Update the 'poll_options' textarea
            // Update the dialog display
        }

    }, // add_option

    validate_add_option : function(){

        var t = this,                                   // This object
            new_option = $('#new_option').val(),        // The new option that the user wishes to add
            options_text = $('#poll_options').text(),   // The text form the predefined options textarea, i.e. any existing options
            options = options_text.split("\n");         // The predefiend options as an array

        /** Check to see if this option already exists */
        t.validation.empty = (new_option === '') ? true : false;

        /** Check to see if this option already exists */
        t.validation.exists = $.inArray(new_option, options);

        /** Ensure the option passed all validity checks */
        t.validation.valid = (t.validation.empty === false && t.validation.exists === -1) ? true : false;

    } // validate_add_option

};
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a type error.

Comment: It's a programming question. Isn't that exactly what this website is about?!

Comment: it's about questions that are actually useful to other people. That's its primary purpose, not to debug your code

Comment: I think if you had used a debugger, you would have found the problem yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: Anyway @DavidGard check this post out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed and have a good weekend in Devon :)

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled the variable.

```
// this 
t.validtaion = {};
// should be 
t.validation = {};
```

Comment: Thanks you, I couldn't see that for looking! Thank goodness the weekend starts in 15 minutes!

Comment: @DavidGard lol no prob. sometimes you just need new eyes to solve a problem.